# What is the data value for a thick splash potion?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm creating an Add-on. But I need a Brewing recipe for bottle o' Enchanting. It uses a Thick Splash potion as input. But I don't know its data (damage) value. What is it?

Comment: Try 3 (that's the [data value for splash potions](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Potion#Bedrock_Edition) and it might be the same for splash potions).

Comment: Should i do something like "item":"minecraft:splash_potion" and add "data":3? But the input is like "input":[potion id]

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the vanilla behaviour pack, which can be downloaded from the [Minecraft Add-Ons page](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons).

I found this recipe for creating a potion of weakness using a thick potion in `recipes/brew_thick_fermented_spider_eye.json`:

```
{
  "format_version": "1.12",
  "minecraft:recipe_brewing_mix": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:brew_thick_fermented_spider_eye"
    },

    "tags": [ "brewing_stand" ],

    "input": "minecraft:potion_type:thick",
    "reagent": "minecraft:fermented_spider_eye",
    "output": "minecraft:potion_type:weakness"
  }

}
```

It seems like you should use `"minecraft:potion_type:thick"` for the input for your brewing recipe.

Comment: But how can I make the input as a thick splash potion?